# the tag value in xml keeps unchange (php+xml)

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to change the tag value, but it is unsuccessful. Here is my xml format and php code, when I am using the $polls->poll[0]->person[0]="change", it works fine...:

```js
$fname = getPollFile();
$polls = simplexml_load_file($fname);

foreach ($polls->poll as $poll){   
  foreach($poll->person as $person){
    $person = "process";
   }
}
   
$polls->asXML($fname);
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<polls>
   <poll title="Ccccc">
      <person id="111">active</person>
      <person id="222">active</person>
   </poll>
</polls>
```

Comment: `$person` in that context is just a variable, not the value of the `person` node.

Comment: but if I do "echo $person" it will show the value of the node...does it mean that I should  work with incrementing the $polls->poll[$x]->person[$x] and than chang the value?

Comment: Yes. The inner part only will be sufficient, in order to do `$poll->person[$x]="new value"`.